# pass data from multiple angular directives to a single angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following angular and html file:

```js
var app = angular.module("directiveApp", [])

app.directive("directiveone", function(){
 return{
  restrict: "E",
  template:'<div><input type="text" ng-model="textOne"></div>'
 };

});

app.directive("directivetwo", function(){
 return{
  restrict: "E",
  template:'<div><input type="text" ng-model="textTwo"></div>'
 };

});

app.directive("directivethree", function(){
 //display textOne and textTwo in the template of this directive.
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="directiveApp">
<head>
 <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src = "directiveApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<directiveone></directiveone>
<directivetwo></directivetwo>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to print the value inserted into ng-models textOne and textTwo using the directivethree. How can i pass data from both those directives and print them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your directive dont have scope, all your variables are shared so you can simply:

```
app.directive("directivethree", function(){
    return{
        restrict: "E",
        template:'<div>{{textOne}}{{textTwo}}</div>'
    };

})
```

This will work until your directives are in 'same place', i.e. if u put one of them inside ng-repeat this will stop working - thats why really better is to add parameters to all your directives, so i.e. you can use directive1 in one place, directive2 in another and directive3 in the third.
http://plnkr.co/edit/8KFQGsq6hxVwrdtGnW1g?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The output of your code produces something like the following: {"a":"textBox1", "b":"textBox2"}. Can i print jus the values entered in the textbox and not the object associated with it?

Answer (score 0):

You always want to have a dot in `ng-model` or in other words, use objects not primitives.

This way it is very easy to use inheritance to share data across various parts of the app. This is a very important aspect of working with angular scopes.

As for sharing across your directives, if they all are in same controller scope, you already share scopes between them so long as directive's don't have an isolated scope.

If they are in different controller scopes, or any of them have an isolated scope, use a service to store the object(s) and inject that service where needed. Objects aren't copied when a variable is assigned an object, it is only a reference to that object. Thus assigning the same object to multiple variables within the app binds them all together.